# Routing error for RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I installed rails admin  (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). But now when i go to localhost:3000 i get the following error

`No route matches {:controller=>"devise/access", :action=>"logout"}`.

I have added the following to the top of my routes.rb but am still getting the above error when i go to localhost:3000 or localhost:3000/admin

```
devise_for :railsadmin_users
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

How can i fix this ?

Thank You

Comment: Which version of ruby you are using?

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3p455

Comment: Try adding this line in routes.rb: get devise_access/logout

Comment: Added get 'device_access/logout' to my routes.rb. Now localhost:3000 works but localhost:3000/admin gives me the same error i.e. No route matches {:controller=>"devise/access", :action=>"logout"}

Comment: Hope you forgot to add resources in routes.rb: try this resources "devise_access"

Comment: I added resources "device_access" but its giving same error when i go to localhost:3000/admin. FYI, since i already had a users table in my database i have railsadmin_users being used by rails admin. So when i go to localhost:3000/admin, it gets redirected to http://localhost:3000/railsadmin_users/sign_in and i get the above error

Answer (score 0):

These are my admin routes using Devise, hope it helps.

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/registrations", :passwords => "devise/passwords" }

mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```